$\mathsf{NP}$ vs. $\mathsf{coNP}$ and sparse sets
Consider the following statement:

If there exists a sparse set of negative (the ones whose answer is no) instances $I$ such that for every negative instance $a$ there exists $i_a\in I$ and a polynomial time verifiable proof that shows that since $i_a$ is negative, then $a$ also is negative, then $\mathsf{coNP}\subset\mathsf{NP}/poly$.

An abstract example could be a sparse set $I$ of graphs such that for some $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem on graphs every negative instance of that problem is sub-isomorphic to a polynomial sized member of $I$.
Is it possible to strengthen the claim by getting rid of the advice akin to Mahaney's theorem? Also, if such a set exists, does that invalidate Berman-Hartmanis conjecture?
